# Jest: Cannot find resolver for:

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, jestjs

When I run my Jest tests, around 80% of them fail due to the

```
cannot find resolver for: <config.name>
at getResolver (../node_modules/jest-runner/build/testWorker.js:153:11)
```

I have tried to run the test with the argument `runInBand` and it seems to work just fine, the issue is when I try to run the test with the default multithread.

- Is there a possibility that I broke something with the `jest.config`?
- I do not want to run the tests on a single thread

Jest version - `24.8.0`

### jest.config

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/src/utils/'
  ],
  coverageReporters: [
    'json',
    'html',
    'text',
    'lcov'
  ],
  coverageThreshold: {
    'global': {
      'branches': 35,
      'functions': 41,
      'lines': 55,
      'statements': 53
    }
  },
  globals: {
    _: require('lodash')
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/../src/utils/__mocks__//fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less|jsf)$': '<rootDir>/../src/utils/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
    '(flags|devices)$': '<rootDir>/../src/utils/__mocks__/styleMock.js'
  },
  roots: [
    '../'
  ],
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/jest.init.js'
  ],
  snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: [
    '**/__tests__/**/*.spec.js?(x)',
    '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x)'
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '/test/'
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!webapps-frontend-components).+(js|jsx)$'
  ]
}
```

### jest.init

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15'

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

global.React = React
global.shallow = shallow
global.render = render
global.mount = mount
```